Cannot convert from `std::initializer_list` to `std::thread`
I am learning about C++ std::thread API and I am writing a naive parallel implementation of std::accumulate. The idea of the exercise is simply to build a toy example, and become more proficient at writing multi-threaded code.

I am not able to resolve the following compiler error or make good sense of it.
How do I ensure that the compiler correctly deduces the types. The std::accumulate in the standard template library properly deduces types, without any type hints. Do you guys have any suggestions to improve my code, so I can achieve something similar?

C:\Data\dev\parallel_accumulate\include\parallel_accumulate.h(54,38): error C2440:'<function-style-cast>': 
cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::thread'
[C:\Data\dev\parallel_accumulate\build\parallel_accumulate.vcxproj]

./include/parallel_accumulate.h
#ifndef PARALLEL_ACCUMULATE_H
#define PARALLEL_ACCUMULATE_H

#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename Iterator, typename Container>
T sequential_fold(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init, T& result)
{
    result = std::accumulate(first, last, init);
};

template <typename T_elem, typename T_accum, typename Iterator, typename Container>
void sequential_fold(Iterator first, Iterator last, T_accum init, std::function<T_accum(T_elem, T_accum)> func, T_accum& result)
{
    result = std::accumulate(first, last, init, func);
};

template <typename T_elem, typename T_accum, typename Iterator, typename Container>
T_accum parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T_elem init, std::function<T_accum(T_elem, T_accum)> func)
{
    unsigned long const length = std::distance(first, last);
    if (!length)
        return init;
    unsigned const int min_block_size = 25;

    // This bit is a clever piece of code. To calculate the maximum number of threads that should be spawned
    // you can divide the total number of elements (length) / by the minimum block size. If the container
    // has #elements in the interval [1,min_block_size), then atleast 1 thread will be spawned. 
    unsigned long const max_threads = static_cast<unsigned long const>((length + min_block_size - 1)/min_block_size);

    //The actual number of threads to run is the minimum of your calculated maximum and the 
    //number of hardware threads. You don't want to run more threads than the hardware can support(oversubscription),
    //because context switching will mean that more threads will decrease the performance. 
    
    // If the call to std::threads::hardware_concurrency() returned 0, you'd substitute a number of
    // your choice; in this case, I have chosen 2. You don't want to run too many threads, 
    // because that would slow things down on a single-core machine, but likewise you don't want
    // to run too few threads, you'd be passing up on available concurrency.
    unsigned long const hardware_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    unsigned long const num_threads = std::min(hardware_threads == 0 ? 2 : hardware_threads, max_threads);
    unsigned long const block_size = static_cast<unsigned long const>(length / num_threads);

    // Now, that we know how many threads we have, we can create a vector<T_accum> object for the intermediate
    // results and a std::vector<std::thread> for the threads. 
    std::vector<T_accum> results(num_threads);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    Iterator it = first;
    for(int i{0};i<num_threads; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(sequential_fold, it, it + block_size, func, std::ref(results[i]))) ;
        it += block_size;
    }

    for(auto& t : threads)
        t.join();
    
    return std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), init, func);
}

#endif

./src/main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "parallel_accumulate.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(50, 1);
    std::function<double(double, double)> sum = [](double element, double accum){
        return accum + element;
    };

    auto it = v.begin();
    double result = parallel_accumulate<double, double, std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>>(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, sum);
    return 0;
}

./CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.30.3)
project(parallel_accumulate)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

set(SOURCES
    src/main.cpp
)

include_directories(include)

add_executable(parallel_accumulate ${SOURCES})  



std::thread(sequential_fold, ...) - sequential_fold is not a funtion, but a function template (or rather one of 2 function templates). You need to instantiate it with template arguments in order to get a function for std::thread.

You might be interested in this article too : C++23’s New Fold Algorithms part of the article also describes how to run fold in parallel using the standard library directly

[OT]: It is often better to place deducible type at the end, so you don't have to provide them and can just call the template function as regular function (or at least with a minimum of explicit template arguments)

You need to instantiate sequential_fold before providing to the std::thread, i.e.:
threads.push_back (std::thread (
    sequential_fold<T_elem, T_accum, Iterator, void>, 
    it, 
    it + block_size, 
    T_accum{},       // provide an init value 
    func, 
    std::ref(results[i])
));

Demo
By the way, don't forget to provide an argument for the init parameter of sequential_fold. And also the last template parameter Container doesn't seem to be used.

Is it possible to refactor the code, so that I don't have to supply explicit type arguments in the function call, and have the compiler deduce them for me?

@Quasar you'll need a lambda function that forwards parameters for that.

@Quasar, it is possible by creating your own callable struct that could postpone the TAD (see here) but I guess more modern ways to do this exist.

@edrezen, sorry, what's the whole point of wrapping your block accumulate function in a struct? I don't quite get, how it helped postpone TAD.

@GuillaumeRacicot, let me experiment with that. I am (re)-learning C++ (after 15 years) ground up. So, std::forward() is a bit new to me.

@Quasar, The initial point is that your template method sequential_fold is not a function until it has been instantiated with some types. Then, you can notice the first argument of the std::thread constructor is an object that is "callable" (which can be many things including a function or a struct providing operator()). Then, the thread starts executing what is required by calling this callable argument with the other arguments.

At this point, the TAD is possible by infering the template parameters of operator() from the type information of the arguments of the callable.

You can have a look here

You cannot pass a overloaded function / template function like this. You'll need to lift it first. To do that defined such macro:
#defined FWD(...) static_cast<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)&&>(__VA_ARGS__)

#define LIFT(F) \
    [&](auto&&... args) \
    noexcept(noexcept(F(FWD(args)...))) \
        -> decltype(F(FWD(args)...)) { \
            return F(FWD(args)...); \
        }

Then use it like so:
threads.push_back(std::thread(LIFT(sequential_fold), it, it + block_size, func, std::ref(results[i]))) ;

